# How to convert year, month, date to only year in python?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

This is my output now

```
Year        Value
2010-12-31  50
2011-12-31  38
2012-12-31  84
```

This is what I want

```
Year Value
2010 50
2011 38
2012 84
```

How do I get the desired output using pandas?

```py
df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"])
df.set_index("Year").groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="Y"))["Value"].sum()
```

I set the frequency to year and the sum of the values was calculated by year perfectly. However, the year column displays the day and month. I just want the year.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  `datetime` formatting is part of any tutorial on the data type.  We expect you to do this research before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
out = df.groupby(df['Year'].dt.year)['Value'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using regular expressions. From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

```py
df["Year"] = df["Year"].str.findall(r"\d\d\d\d")[0]
```

This will return the DataFrame exactly as you wish if your dates are pattern consistent.